# Iterating DataView for Update

Tags: asp.net, linq, dataview

I have a DataView which filters

```
inputView.RowFilter = "isnull(" + ID1 + ",'')<>'' and isnull(" + reason + ",0)=0";
```

after this filter i have to update "`IsVerified`" column of  `inputView` to "1"

Is there something in LINQ to execute the  following?

```
inputView.RowFilter.ForEach(x=>x.Field<IsVerified> =1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use LINQ on your DataView, you'll have to create your own extension method on the DataView. The DataView does not natively have a .`ToList()` method, which is where the .`ForEach()` is defined.

**Create your Extension Method for the DataView.**

```
public static class DataViewExtensions
{
    public static List<DataRowView> ToList(this DataView v)
    {
        List<DataRowView> foo = new List<DataRowView>();

        for (int i = 0; i < v.Count; i++)
        {
            foo.Add(v[i]);
        }
        return foo;
    }

}
```

Your DataView can now be called this like:

```
inputView.ToList().ForEach(x=>x["IsVerified"]=1);
```

Some developers may prefer the full .NET `foreach (var x in y)` statement, but this will do the same.

A full console application proo-of-concept: http://pastebin.com/y9z5n6VH